# Textfield data is getting too small, when we enter more data into the textbox

Tags: java, itext

If I apply,

```
 text.setOptions(TextField.MULTILINE | TextField.REQUIRED);
```

to my text field, then I can enter more data, but the problem is the data is getting too small, then it becomes scrollable.

Can we get a scrollbar instead, before it gets too small?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use textarea instead of textfield as you want multiple lines. And then you need to put textArea to ScrollPane to get scrollbar.

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10, 30);
ScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
```

Comment: Considering the [iText] tag I assume the OP meant a text field in a PDF generated by iText.